# If $U$ is orthogonal to itself why can you say $ U = U\Sigma V^T$ where $\Sigma = I_n $ and $ V = I_n$

Tags: linear-algebra

How can you tell

$$ U = U\Sigma V^T$$

$$\Sigma = I_n  \:\:\:\:\:\: V = I_n$$

$$\text{if} \:\: UU^T = I_n$$

by inspection without solving for the singular values of $U$

From my understanding SVD

$$A = U\Sigma V^T$$

SED

$$A = U\wedge U^T$$

I understand that

$$UU^T = I_n$$

means that $U$ contains its own eigenvector, but is the choosing of $V$ arbitrary as long as $V$ is orthogonal with $U$?

Edit: this is the original question

Given:

$$U=\frac{1}{3}\begin{bmatrix}-1 &2&2\\ 2&-1&2\\ 2&2&-1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Find a singular decomposition of $U$ (Hint use the result that $U$ is orthongoal)

Solution: We can write $U=U\Sigma V^T$ with $\Sigma =V=I_n$

This means that the left singular vectors of $U$ are in $U$ and the right singular vectors of $U$ are the unit basis vectors and all the singular values of $U$ are equal to 1

My Question:

I would like to know if $U$ is orthogonal is the singular values necessary = 1, why is that so? And if so is $V^T$ arbitrary, as long as $V^T$ is orthogonal to V?

Comment: You need some quantifiers on this if this has any chance of being interpreted as being true. See [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=svd+%7B%7B1%2Fsqrt%282%29%2C+1%2Fsqrt%282%29%7D%2C+%7B1%2Fsqrt%282%29%2C+-1%2Fsqrt%282%29%7D%7D) for a counter example.

Comment: Sorry, that is what I meant, I edit the question

Comment: If $\Sigma=I_n$ and $V=I_n$, then $U=UI_nI_n=U\Sigma V^T$ for any $U$, no? So if $U$ has orthogonal columns, then yes, $U=U\Sigma V^T$ is an SVD of $U$ (if that is the question).

Comment: The edit doesn't address my comment, the counter example still holds.

Comment: Which of this do you want to prove: "Given an orthogonal matrix $U$, it's SVD decomposition necessarily yields $\Sigma =V=I_n$" or "Given an orthogonal matrix $U$, there is an SVD decomposition such that $\Sigma =V=I_n$"? One of them is false and I have provided a counter example. This is what must be clarified.

Comment: @Git Gud, thanks for the reply, I am trying to prove that "Given an orthogonal matrix $U$, there is an SVD decomposition such that $U=U\Sigma V^T  \text{s.t} \:\: \Sigma = V = I_n$

Comment: What is the problem? You cannot see that $U\Sigma V^T$ is an SVD or what happens when multiplying with the identity matrix?

Comment: @PavelJiranek I think the OP wants to know why is that decomposition an SVD without explicitly verifying that it is so.

Comment: @PavelJiranek, to clarify my question, I would like to know if $U$ is orthogonal is the singular values necessary = 1? And if so is $V^T$ arbitrary, as long as $V^T$ is orthogonal to $U$?

Comment: @user87852 Singular values are unique and since $U\Sigma V^T$ with $\Sigma=I$ and $V=I$ is **an** SVD of $U$, necessarily $1$ are the only singular values of $U$. Note that if $Q$ is orthogonal ($Q^TQ=QQ^T=I$), then $U=UQQ^T=(UQ)I(Q^T)$ is also **an** SVD of $U$. I don't understand, what $V^T$ being orthogonal to $U$ means. If it means that $V^TU=0$, then the orthogonality of $U$ would imply that $V=0$.

Comment: @Pavel Jiranek, thanks that makes sense, regarding to the orthogonal it was a typo, I mean is $V^T$ always arbitrary as long as $V^T$ is orthogonal to $V$?

Comment: @user87852 BTW to see that the singular values are unique, note that they are the eigenvalues of $U^TU=I$, so even if you did not believe that the eigenvalues are unique, it is pretty easy to see that there is no other eigenvalue of $I$ than $1$ :)

Comment: @PavelJiranek Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the singular values of a matrix are not distinct  the SVD is not unique. For orthogonal matrices, the singular values are unity and all are non distinct. For your matrix $U$ you would like to get the SVD of U as
$$
U = U \Sigma V^t
$$
where $\Sigma = I$ and $V=I$. However, we may introduce a permutation matrix $P$ in the following way:
$$
U = (U*P)(P^t \Sigma P) (P^tV^t)
$$
where $PP^t = I$. In this case, the new SVD can be written as
$$
U = \hat{U} \hat{\Sigma} \hat{V}^t
$$
where 
$$
\hat{U} = UP, \;\;\; \hat{\Sigma} = P^t \Sigma P, \;\;\; \hat{V} = VP.
$$
When I tried your matrix on Matlab, I got
$$
\hat{U} = 
\left[ \begin{array}{rrr}
-2 & -2 & -1 \\
1 & -2 & 2 \\
-2 & 1 & 2
\end{array}
 \right],\;\;\; 
\hat{\Sigma} = I,\;\;\;\hat{V} = 
\left[ \begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0
\end{array}
 \right].
$$
Thus, $U$ and $\hat{U}$ are different and $V$ is not an identity matrix. If you use a different software package, you may get a different valid answer.